# Does $Δθ=(1/2) (ω_i+ω_f )Δt$ constrain the possible angular acceleration？

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics

For part a of this question:

[image]

I solved it like the following:

[image]

I am confused why there isn't a solution that's larger than 10 rev/s. As the formula I used, $Δθ=1/2 (ω_i+ω_f )Δt$, doesn't seem to me that it constrains the value for the acceleration, I imagine that it's also possible for the acceleration to be a negative value. In other words, the wheel is initially rotating at a much higher angular velocity, then it decreases to 10 rev/s after turning 90 rev in 15 s.

I'm wondering what part of the formula, $Δθ=1/2 (ω_i+ω_f )Δt$, makes sure that this isn't possible, as the solution I got from solving this formula is only possible when the acceleration is positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notation**
$\alpha$ - angular acceleration
$\omega_i$ - initial angular velocity
$\omega_f$ - final angular velocity
$\theta$ - angular displacement

Starting time is considered as 0.

$\frac{d\omega}{dt}=\alpha$
It is given that $\alpha=constant$
$\omega_f=\omega_i+\alpha t\tag{1}$

As $\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\omega$
$\implies d\theta=\omega dt$
$\implies d\theta=(\omega_i+\alpha t)dt$
Integrating on both sides
$\implies \Delta\theta=\omega_i t+\frac{\alpha t^2}{2}$

Putting $\alpha t=\omega_f-\omega_i$ from $(1)$

So, $\Delta\theta=\omega_i t+\frac{(\omega_f-\omega_i)t}{2}$
$\implies \Delta\theta=\frac{\omega_f+\omega_i}{2}t\tag{2}$

Now your doubt is that why (2) holds it might happen that $\alpha$ can be positive or negative and thus $\omega_i$ can be greater than or less than $\omega_f$.
In the above problem it is given that wheel covers 90 revolutions in 15 sec. So on averge it angular velocity is $\frac{90}{15}=6$ revolutions/sec.
But final velcity is $10$ revolutions/sec.
This means that at some point of time the velocity is less than $6$ revolutions/sec only then we get an average of 6 revolution/sec.
But we are given that angular acceleration is constant. So velocity can either decrease or increase in that time interval. It can't be the case that at some interval velocity will decrease and then increase as for that angular acceleration has to change sign so it won't remains constant giving us contradiction.
As at some interval angular velocity has to take value less than $6$ revolutions/sec.
This suggests that over the whole interval velocity will increase continuously thus initial angular velocity will be less that final angular velocity.

So, the take home message is that in the equation $(2)$ the information of angular acceleration is inherent, though it might not be so much evident from the form of equation but we can see this from the derivation.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You used the most convenient rotational kinematics formula to solve this problem.  In looking at this formula, there are four variables, which are $\Delta \theta$, $\omega_i$, $\omega_f$, and $\Delta t$.  Three of these variables are assigned values in the problem statement, so you know the value of $\Delta \theta$, $\omega_f$, and $\Delta t$.  This means that there is one equation with only one unknown.  Since the number of unknowns is equal to the number of equations that you have, and that equation is linear for that unknown variable, there is only one possible solution, which is arrived at by separating the unknown variable and substituting values for the known variables.